# Kotlin - constructor default values and constructor overloading

Tags: kotlin

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo(val bar: String, val baz: Boolean = true) {
    constructor(bar: String) : this(bar, false)
}
```

Without the addition of a secondary constructor, I could call `Foo("")` because the second argument has a default value. This would result in `baz` being `true`.

With the addition of a secondary constructor, I can still call `Foo("")`, except that now `baz` is `false`.

Why does Kotlin not see this as a duplicate constructor signature, since they can both be called with the same arguments?

Comment: You don't need `bar`, it just complicates the example. Interesting. You could still call `Foo("", true)`. It seems it would be useful if it warned that the secondary constructor is meaningless because of the default value.

Comment: my guess is: because it's not implemented yet ;-) from the bytecode-point of view I see 3 constructors... one for `Foo(String, Boolean)`, a synthetic `Foo(String, DefaultConstructorMarker)` which uses the default value and `Foo(String)`... so these are 3 distinct constructors... maybe that's coming... on the other hand I don't know when I ever had such a constellation... and also cost/benefit ratio is probably not so good...

Comment: If you use the 'first' or the 'second' constructor, you always need to provide at least 1 parameter, i.e for `bar`. In the second constructor, you are always delegating to the primary constructor and you are already providing it with a default value which is `false`. Reading from decompiled code, it appears that the compiler generated a synthetic method and where it is providing all signatures with their values. So it does not matter which constructor you call, in the end, all conditions are being met.

Comment: @series0ne does my post answer your question? :)

Comment: @WilliMentzel yes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a look at the bytecode there are actually three constructors generated, as Roland already pointed out.

```
public Foo(@NotNull String bar, boolean baz) { ... }
public Foo(String var1, boolean var2, int var3, DefaultConstructorMarker var4) { ... }
public Foo(@NotNull String bar) { ... }
```

So, there are no duplicate constructor signatures. Now one might ask how Kotlin chooses which overload to take judging from the call-site only.

The overall rationale is that the most specific function/constructor will be chosen from the overload candidates.

This is what the [Kotlin language specification](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlin-spec/#overload-resolution) says about it:

> - For each candidate, we count the number of default parameters not specified in the call (i.e., the number of parameters for which we use
>     the default value);
> - The candidate with the least number of non-specified default parameters is a more specific candidate;

---

I know that you intended this to only be an example, but if something like this happens in a real-world situation one should avoid it like the [Kotlin Language Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-docs.pdf) (page 76) states:

> If you have an object with multiple overloaded constructors that don't
>   call different superclass constructors and can't be reduced to a
>   single constructor with default argument values, prefer to replace the
>   overloaded constructors with factory functions.

```
class Foo2(val bar: String, val baz: Boolean = true) {
    companion object {
        fun factoryCreate(s: String) = Foo2(s, false)
    }
}
```

In this case it will always be clear right away (without thinking about the overloading resolution rules) what `baz` will be after creation.